# dev_appserver.py fails to run when runtime is set to python37

Tags: python, dev-appserver

I am running **dev_appserver.py** on runtime **Python 3.7.1**

My **app.yaml** is as follows.

```
runtime: python37 
api_version: 1

threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*   
  script: main.app 
builtins:
- appstats: on
```

When I run dev_appserver.py I get the following issue.

```
Vinays-MBP:site-web vinayjoseph$ dev_appserver.py .
INFO     2019-01-12 06:58:11,493 sdk_update_checker.py:229] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2019-01-12 06:58:11,991 api_server.py:204] Starting API server at: http://localhost:60384
INFO     2019-01-12 06:58:11,991 api_server.py:629] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore
INFO     2019-01-12 06:58:11,991 api_server.py:632] Saving search indexes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 83, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 79, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 1027, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 1020, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 817, in start
    self._dispatcher.start(options.api_host, apis.port, request_data)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 193, in start
    _module, port = self._create_module(module_configuration, port)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 278, in _create_module
    threadsafe_override=threadsafe_override)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 1178, in __init__
    super(AutoScalingModule, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 558, in __init__
    self._module_configuration)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 254, in _create_instance_factory
    sorted(repr(k) for k in self._RUNTIME_INSTANCE_FACTORIES))))
RuntimeError: Unknown runtime 'python37'; supported runtimes are 'custom', 'go', 'java', 'java7', 'php', 'php55', 'python', 'python27'.
Vinays-MBP:site-web vinayjoseph$
```

Comment: What's unclear about the error message? "python37" is not one of the permitted values for `runtime`.

Comment: Then why does the documentation say I must using python37 as the value for runtime. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime

Comment: You need to update your SDK.